# vba error: type mismatch using booleans

Tags: vba, excel

I am copying over rows that match a criteria from one sheet to another. I set up a bunch of Boolean statements in my for loop to make my if statement a little cleaner and because I will be doing a couple elseif's. I am getting a Type mismatch error in my if statement. Any ideas?

VBA Code:

```
Dim blActive As Boolean
Dim blSeason1 As Boolean
Dim blSeason2 As Boolean
Dim blSeason3 As Boolean
Dim blSeason4 As Boolean
Dim blSeason5 As Boolean
Dim blSeason6 As Boolean
Dim blNA As Boolean
Dim blInter As Boolean
Dim blGlobal As Boolean
Dim blDrop As Boolean
Dim blSMUDrop As Boolean
Dim blPromoDrop As Boolean
Dim blPromoNBR As Boolean
Dim blUSWS As Boolean
Dim blUSMSRP As Boolean
Dim blCanWS As Boolean
Dim blCanMSRP As Boolean
Dim blFOB As Boolean

For i = 2 To lRow_Spec

'Check if Forecast Season = "ACTIVE",
blActive = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 1).Value = "ACTIVE")
'Check for All 6 seasons Seasons(based on "Buy Ready missing info Seasons"
blSeason1 = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(35, 2).Value)
blSeason2 = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(35, 3).Value)
blSeason3 = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(35, 4).Value)
blSeason4 = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(35, 5).Value)
blSeason5 = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(35, 6).Value)
blSeason6 = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 2).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(35, 7).Value)
'Check which Distribution it is (NA, Global,International) Have to break this out b/c each area has different blank checks
blNA = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(24, 9).Value)
blInter = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(24, 11).Value)
blGlobal = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 5).Value = Worksheets(mySheet).Cells(24, 13).Value)
'Checking that status is not irrelevant
blDrop = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Drop")
blSMUDrop = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 3).Value = "SMU Drop")
blPromoDrop = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Promo Drop")
blPromoNBR = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 3).Value = "Promo-NBR")
'Checking for Blanks US WS, US MSRP, Can WS, Can MSRP, FOB
blUSWS = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 22).Value = " ")
blUSMSRP = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 23).Value = " ")
blCanWS = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 24).Value = " ")
blCanMSRP = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 25).Value = " ")
blFOB = (Worksheets("Item_Spec_Data").Cells(i, 26).Value = " ")

If blActive & _
    blNA & _
    (blSeason1 Or blSeason2 Or blSeason3 Or blSeason4 Or blSeason5 Or blSeason6) & _
    blDrop & blSMUDrop & blPromoDrop & blPromoNBR & _
    (blUSWS Or blUSMSRP Or blFOB) _
Then
```

Comment: `&` isn't `And` --  it is for string concatenation, not logical conjunction.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You logical AND instead of & which is used for string concatenation.

```
If blActive AND _
    blNA AND _
    (blSeason1 Or blSeason2 Or blSeason3 Or blSeason4 Or blSeason5 Or blSeason6) AND _
    blDrop AND blSMUDrop AND blPromoDrop AND blPromoNBR AND _
    (blUSWS Or blUSMSRP Or blFOB) _
Then
```